# How to extract multiple columns from one string column using sql

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two columns, in charges column I have different charges like `post`, `neg`, `transfer`, `drawer` charges

| ref_no | charges |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | POSTEX USD 100 B^NEGO USD 200 B^TRAN USD 150 |
| 002 | POSTEX USD 400 B^TRAN USD 350 |
| 003 | NEGO USD 700 B^TRAN USD 350 |
| 004 | DRAW USD 700 |

Now what I want is like this:

| ref_no | POSTEX | NEGO | TRAN | DRAW |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | POSTEX USD 100 | NEGO USD 200 | TRAN USD 150 |  |
| 002 | POSTEX USD 400 |  | TRAN USD 350 |  |
| 003 |  | NEGO USD 700 | TRAN USD 350 |  |
| 004 |  |  |  | DRAW USD 700 |

I have tried use `lateral view` + `split` but its not working, is there some other way I can do it using SparkSQL or MySql?

Comment: Search for mysql split string..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using [`regexp_extract`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#regexp_extract) function in Spark SQL:

```py
spark.sql(r"""
    SELECT  ref_no,
            regexp_extract(charges, '(POSTEX USD \\d+)', 1)  AS POSTEX,
            regexp_extract(charges, '(NEGO USD \\d+)', 1)    AS NEGO,
            regexp_extract(charges, '(TRAN USD \\d+)', 1)    AS TRAN,
            regexp_extract(charges, '(DRAW USD \\d+)', 1)    AS DRAW
    FROM    my_table
""").show()

#+------+--------------+------------+------------+------------+
#|ref_no|        POSTEX|        NEGO|        TRAN|        DRAW|
#+------+--------------+------------+------------+------------+
#|   001|POSTEX USD 100|NEGO USD 200|TRAN USD 150|            |
#|   002|POSTEX USD 400|            |TRAN USD 350|            |
#|   003|              |NEGO USD 700|TRAN USD 350|            |
#|   004|              |            |            |DRAW USD 700|
#+------+--------------+------------+------------+------------+
```